# Tables aliased with the same are treated as different tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this snippet:

```
users = users.alias('t1')

stmt = select([
    users.c.name
]).select_from(
    users
).where(
    users.c.name == 'Jack'
)
```

where `users` is a `Table`. This works fine. It compiles to:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM users AS t1
WHERE t1.name = :name_1
```

However, if I do:

```
stmt = select([
    users.alias('t1').c.name
]).select_from(
    users.alias('t1')
).where(
    users.alias('t1').c.name == 'Jack'
)
```

I get three different tables with the same name:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM users AS t1, users AS t1, users AS t1
WHERE t1.name = :name_1
```

The problem is that I'm building the expressions across
different functions and I want to avoid passing `users.alias()`
around. Can I configure SQLAlchemy to recognize tables based on the
names I provide alone? (`t1` in my example)

Comment: Configure as in?? you are using aliasing to tell Sqlalchemy how to treat your table.

Comment: As exemplified by code snippet, I'm not telling SQLAlchemy how to treat my table. Or at least not effectively.

Comment: I'm using the same alias names and yet tables are treated as different.

Comment: yup because you are specifying aliasing three times. It does not have any lookahead or look backward feature to look for the previous declaration.

Comment: You could create your own lookup based on name. As you've noticed SQLA differentiates the table/alias objects by their object identity or something comparable, not by name. Quoting the docs, "The `name` parameter is optional, and **provides the name to use in the rendered SQL**"

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the way to go. Thank you for the suggestion.